# Delete all even numbers from an array (Ruby)?

Tags: ruby

I'm doing the Ruby Monk tutorial to further some ruby learning and I got stumped on what should be an easier question. I know the answer is right in front of me but I cannot seem to figure it out:

Delete all the even numbers from the array given below:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Any help would be great!

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at what [methods are available on array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html)? Can you see anything that might be useful for deleting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here it is.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
a.delete_if &:even?
```

Comment: Please use `even?` instead of doing the check like you do.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simpler way

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].delete_if {|n| n%2 == 0 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to relax y'all. My name is Ron & I'm taking the RubyMonk course, too. The issue is we're over-analyzing a simple question. We are asked to DELETE all the
EVEN numbers from the array [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]. After reading your great answers, I went back & re-worked it like this:
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]-[2,4,6,8], & I passed it with the GREEN light to proceed onward. Thank you very much for your time..

Answer (score 0):

I think Gull's suggestion will serve you best. But there is also another option if you want another array that contains only the odd numbers:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b = a.select {|x| x.odd? }
```

Also in his answer you could use `even?` instead of `x % 2 == 0`

Comment: Note that you could use `a.select(&:odd?)` instead of using the full block form.

Answer (score 0):

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].delete_if {|n| n %2 == 0 }
```

should be your answer depending on your previous lessons.